# Return client error if part of request body in HTTP POST is null in Spring Boot in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

Spring Boot + Kotlin:

When a required `Boolean` in request body is not present (or it is null), then it is mapped to false.

How should I improve validation so that client error is returned? I even tried `@field:NonNull` and `@field:Valid` but they don't help..

Here's an example:

```
data class MyRequestBody(
    val value1: String,
    val value2: Boolean
)

@PostMapping("/blabla")
fun someMethod(
    @RequestBody requestBody: MyRequestBody,
): CompletableFuture<MyResponse> = unwrappedAsync {
    ...
}
```

For this request:

```
sample request body: { "value1": "abc", "value2": null }
```

`MyRequestBody` contains `value1='abc', value2=false`

In other words, how to I prevent this `null -> false` mapping and make it a client error instead?

Comment: You can use `Boolean?` instead of `Boolean` so that if you receive null for value2 it would not cause value2 to be forced to false. And use `@field:NonNull` for this field. P.S. to trigger automatic validation you need to add `@Valid` near `@RequestBody`

Comment: Boolean? + @field:NonNull works.. but it looks so workaroundish + I have to use !! to read the value.. is there any other way?

Comment: Mariusz, another way is to mark `value2` with Jackson's `@JsonProperty(required = true)`

Comment: It requires a parameter with this name but it doesn't check of it is nonnull... -.-

Comment: If you don't want to use the `Boolean? + @field:NonNull` solution then a custom deserializer for `MyRequestBody` is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the java validation with NotNull annotation?

```kotlin
data class MyRequestBody(
    val value1: String,
    @get:NotNull
    val value2: Boolean
)
```

Even you can use the annotation with the non-null boolean type.